# How to remove border from inline CKEditor's editable area?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using inline CKEditor on my page (so it's only toolbar and editable line). In Chrome this editable line has a blue border. In Firefox it's without border (you see only blinking cursor and CKEditor's toolbar).

I want to have same border for that editable line in Chrome and Firefox. I tried this

```
CKEDITOR.addCss(".cke_editable{border-color: #FF0000;}");
```

but it didn't replace that blue border - only added another one into it (more precisely they are partialy overlapping).

Answer (score 3):

[`CKEDITOR.addCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-addCss) is for internal purposes, e.g. plugin development. Also the blue border that you experienced is not a `border` but `outline`. Extend your `contents.css` with the following rules (or specify it directly on that page), and it should be just fine:

```
div[contenteditable] {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/3RKa4/).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that `contents.css`. I was searching that for really long time. In my original solution I used `.cke_focus` instead of `div[contenteditable]`, but it worked only when it was applied to div that already had some border. Can you explain me why?

Comment: If you used JSFiddle, it would be much easier to figure it out. Some external styles? Who knows ;)

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I find solution by myself, but it used `CKEDITOR.addCss` method again. When I came here to post it, I noticed [oleq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249059/how-to-remove-border-from-inline-ckeditors-editable-area/23266588?noredirect=1#23266588), so I updated my solution according to that.

As I wrote Firefox doesn't display that outline, so if I want to have the same border in Chrome and Firefox, I had to remove outline and replace it with border (which is correctly displayed in both browsers). So I append this to CKEditor's `contents.css`:

```
div[editable] {
    border-color: #a0c0e4; 
    border-radius: 2px; 
    outline: none;
}
```